# I am looking for an api that provides lyrics for requested song

Tags: android, android-music-player

Is there any api available that return full lyrics of song...?

I go through many blogs and found that [musicxmatch](http://musixmatch.com/) provide good api for lyrics.

It only return 30% lyrics of full song.

**`"lyrics_copyright":"Lyrics powered by www.musiXmatch.com. This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use and only 30% of the lyrics are returned."`**

Comment: Give [this](http://www.chartlyrics.com/api.aspx) a try. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158064/apis-which-provide-lyrics-of-requested-song)

Comment: http://cn.last.fm/api

Comment: and [this](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/lyricwiki-api-get-song-lyrics-code/2008/03/31) as well.

Comment: @PurpleDroid I have tried this too is working for limited song only..!!

Comment: I think Lyrics Wiki is not provide API.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow nowadays (see item #5 on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).